# pandas, python,after HDF5 file copy, i met error message when i try to open copied file

Tags: python, pandas, copy, hard-drive

my code is

```
def Operation_Store_Close(self,op_store):
    op_path = 'c:/data/operation/operation.hdf'
    backup = 'c:/data/operation/operation_backup.hdf'
    op_store.close ()
    os.remove(backup)
    shutil.copy2 (op_path, backup)
    with pd.HDFStore(backup) as bstore:
        print(bstore[bstore.keys()[0]])
    return
```

from

```
 print(bstore[bstore.keys()[0]]),
```

i met message as following.

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 417, in __getitem__
 return self.get(key)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 634, in g et
return self._read_group(group)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 1272, in _read_group
 return s.read(**kwargs)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 2788, in read
placement=items.get_indexer(blk_items))
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2082, in get_indexer
raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
pandas.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Is there any good way to avoid above message.
thanks for your advice in advance.

Comment: In the error message there should be the line of your code. It is not clear now, which line raises the exeption.

Comment: print(bstore[bstore.keys()[0]]), i put this code for examine. error message raised from this line.